# MultiThreading inside Loop and Wait Threads WinForms and C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, wait

I'm in trouble with this code. I'm using .Net (C#) with Winform Application.

I need to run RunProgram Method which has loop that make a call to a method named ListLoop. 
In this function there is a forach that creates 1 thread for each element a list.

(Please Read the code before continue to read the description so you could understand what i'm talking about )

The problem is that if i dont make any control in the "for" (RunProgram Method) it starts (of course) 10 times The ListLoop Function.
So i would add in that "For" a code which wait that all Threads are terminated, so i can do Something and Then continue with the next loop.

I tried thread.join() but it freeze my UI application 
(it's Application which inside has a WebControl Browser).

Even if i Try to play with returnThred and with thread.isAlive it still freezes UI.

If i hadn't the Multithread i'll dont stay here with those problems but it's the only good solution for my program i think.

Is there a simple solution for my code?
Update: Maybe it'snt clear my question.

*I just want run the ListLoop X times but before start the next one i want wait           that all threads are dead (That ones of the first call) so i can do some control and continue with the loop inside RunProgram.*

**Update2** I have this UI application which has a WebBrowser Control. I have a List of Links Object (each element of this class has string url and idHost =1 2 3 4...1 for google 2 for yahoo etc...)
I want make a loop where my program start a newTab (with Method AddTab(url) ) for each element of the list. When all links are opened (and so all the threads are deads and) i need to do something that count how many pages opened and who was the idHost save it and start another Loop with the list(This list take random element from a Bigger List)

**Update 3** I just tried with BackGround Worker but i cant use it cause the WebKit that i'm using give COM error. Something for the Tasks.

Thanks

```
private void RunProgram()
{
  List<Links> TheList = new List<Links>();
  //Do something to Populate the List
  List<System.Threading.Thread> returnThread = new List<.....>();
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    returnThread=ListLoop(TheList);
       //      ???????????
      //   When Loop Method has finished and all threads stopped
     //    Do something
    //     Continue for the next Loop
  }
}

private List<System.Threading.Thread> ListLoop(List<Links> list)
{
  List<System.Threading.Thread> threading = new List<System.Threading.Thread>();
  foreach (Links link in list)
  {
    Links tmp = new Links();
    tmp = link;

    var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(p =>
    {
      lock (l)
      {
        Action action = () =>
        {
          AddTab(tmp);
        };
        this.Invoke(action);

        if (tmp.idHost == 1) //if IDhost == Google wait 5sec
        {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        else
        {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
      }
    });
    threading.Add(thread);
    thread.Start();
  }
  return threading;
}
```

Comment: A few questions: You are locking `l` - what's `l`? Also why are you using `Thread.Sleep` for specific idHosts?? And what's up with adding each of the threads to a list? Your code pretty much look flawed. If you could elaborate a bit on what you're actually trying to do, we could come with more qualified answers.

Comment: i have List which has inside url and ihHost. Now i have a UI with a webBrowser Control. I want that it add an AddTab for each element of the List. But if one of those element has idHost==1 (google) to start the next AddTab i need to wait 5 seconds.After that it opened all elelement i need to do something , like a check and after that it should start again the new loop with new threads etc.... L instead is a var l = new Object(); just to lock something and dont Lock my UI. I'm going to explain the problem well in the question.

Comment: Should each tab have its own thread, since you don't use TPL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question properly, but:

You work asynchronously here... You can't wait in your code without stopping the GUI.

I think your solution will be to separate your function into 2 parts - The 1st one you just written, and the second one works after the threads are all dead.

For the second part (check the threads) I'd use either another thread (That waits until the threads are dead than continues to your code) or a Timer if you'd like to save threads and integrate easily into the main form

**UPDATE:**
Here is an example of how a blocking function that doesn't block the GUI thread:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System;

namespace Threads
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public event EventHandler OnSomethingFinishes;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            OnSomethingFinishes += new EventHandler(Form1_OnSomethingFinishes);
        }

        void Form1_OnSomethingFinishes(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Form1_OnSomethingFinishesSafe), sender, e);
        }

        void Form1_OnSomethingFinishesSafe(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Done!";
        }

        private void BlockingFunction(object a_oParameter)
        {
            // Do something that blocks
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            if (OnSomethingFinishes != null)
                OnSomethingFinishes(this, null);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread l_oThread = new Thread(BlockingFunction);
            l_oThread.Start();

            this.Text = "Please Wait...";
        }
    }
}
```

button1 starts the process. Notice that you have to invoke the function after the event is handled to move the control to the main GUI thread

Hope this helps

Comment: I just want start the ListLoop X times but before start the next one i want wait that all threads are dead so i can do some control and continue with the loop inside RunProgram. Btw create a thread that control if other threads are still alive could be an idea.

Comment: As you said, if you don't want to freeze the GUI thread - You can't "wait" in your function that is run by the GUI thread. Add another thread to run this whole function, and use Thread.Join, Mutex.WaitAll, or something like that. That way the GUI won't freeze at all. After the function finishes - Write an event from the thread to the GUI, and invoke it to the GUI thread. I'll add an example, hold on

Answer (score 0):

If `RunProgram` is called from your main application, it will freeze your main form if it sleeps or waits for threads to terminate.  You should run the `RunProgram` method in its own thread, so it can then create the worker threads, and then you can wait for the threads to complete in your for loop before starting new ones.

You could use [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) to signal when threads are finished so you can simply wait on the AutoResetEvent before continuing the loop.  The [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class may be a good class to look at for creating your threads as well.

Comment: I just tried with BackGroundWorker but it doesnt work cause the Webkit library that i'm using now(Give a COM error with backGround).